# swift 3 numberofrowsinsection runs before viewwillappear fetches reminders

Tags: swift, swift3, reminders, ekeventstore

Would like to ask for some help in retrieving reminders. Seems like numberOfRowsInSection and is getting called even before eventStore.fetchReminders has finished. Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("****viewWillAppear")
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.eventStore = EKEventStore()
    self.reminders = [EKReminder]()
    //Added to initialize
    self.reminders.removeAll()
    self.eventStore!.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.reminder, completion:
        {(granted, error) in
            if granted
            {
                let predicate = self.eventStore.predicateForReminders(in: nil)
                self.eventStore.fetchReminders(matching: predicate, completion: { (reminders: [EKReminder]?) -> Void in
                    self.reminders = reminders
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        //Added 
                        self.reminders = reminders
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })

            }
            else 
            {
                print("The app is not permitted to access reminders, make sure to grant permission in the settings and try again")
            }
    })

    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("*****numberOfRowsInSection")
    print("numberOfRowsInSection reminders \(self.reminders.count)")
    return self.reminders.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    print("****titleForHeaderInSection")
    print("titleForHeaderInSection reminders \(self.reminders.count)")
    return "test"
}
```

I tried putting it in viewDidLoad but same thing happens, the self.reminders.count in numberofRowsInSection is returning 0. I also tried to call fetchReminders OUTSIDE of requestAccess (because I thought requestAccess was not firing), but I end up with the same thing. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
  Would really appreciate any advise!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to add super.viewWillAppear() in your viewWillAppear? Also you should call the following in your viewDidLoad() :     self.eventStore!.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.reminder, completion:

Comment: hi mikael, thanks! I have added the super.viewWillAppear. and I have also added the requestAccess in viewDidLoad. I'm getting the same result :(

Comment: At least you get a better code here. Even if It didn't fix your issue ;) happy to see that you could fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. The `UITableViewController` attempts to display the contents of the table view as the view controller is being shown. You should initialize `self.reminders` with an empty array at the start of `viewDidLoad` so the table view initially shows no results.

Then, once your access of the event store is complete, your code to reset `self.reminders` and reload the table view will be called.

One critical change you should make is to set `self.reminders` inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async()` block. This ensures the data source is updated just before the table is reloaded and not before hand. In other words, update your code to:

```
self.eventStore.fetchReminders(matching: predicate, completion: { (reminders: [EKReminder]?) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.reminders = reminders
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
```

One other change to consider is to initially set `self.reminders` to `nil` and have your table view data source methods treat this as a signal to show one row that says "loading" (or something similar). Otherwise your users may wonder why they are starring at a mostly blank screen for a brief period of time.

Comment: thanks maddy! what do you mean by "set the self.reminders inside the dispatchqeueue.main.async() block"?

Comment: by the way my apologies, i forgot to mention, im new to swift. based on my findings, viewWillAppear fires then it stops when it sees    "self.eventStore!.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.reminder, completion:" then it jumps straight to view numberOfSections function. After a few loops (2-3) then it comes back again and runs the fetchReminders code.

Comment: See my updated answer showing what I meany about the `async` block.

Comment: hi maddy, i have updated my code above. seems like it's doing the same thing. here is my log:     *****View Did Load...
BEFORE PredicateForReminders....
AFTER PredicateForReminders....
****viewWillAppear
****numberOfSections
Reminders count 0
****titleForHeaderInSection
titleForHeaderInSection reminders 0

Comment: Have you used the debugger and verified that the call to `fetchReminders` is actually being called? And are you sure the completion block is being called? And are there any reminders in the results?

Comment: hi maddy, yes i can see the reminders. But they are only showing up after calling titleForHeaderInSection and numberOfSections 3 times, with the first 2 times where reminder count is returning 0 :(

Comment: To be clear, you will see a bunch of calls to your data source methods when the view controller first appears and there is no data. Once the reminders are loaded and you call `reloadData`, you will see them called again but this time with however many reminders were loaded.

Comment: So is it working now? Are you seeing the reminders after they are loaded? And I see you have two calls to `self.reminders = reminders`. Don't do that. Just have the one inside the `async` call.

Comment: hi maddy, i can see them, but my issue is the function numberOfSections where I had to hardcode return 1 because when i reference the reminder array, it's returning 0 : func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("****numberOfSections")
        print ("Reminders count \(self.reminders.count)")
        //return nameDictionary.count
        if nameDictionary.count > 0 {
            return nameDictionary.keys.count
        }
        
        return 1

    }

Comment: `numberOfSections` should be 1. It's `numberOfRowsInSection` that needs to be based on the `self.reminders.count`.

Comment: hi maddy, actually in my numberOfRowsInSection i have a logic to group the reminders by inserting them into a dictionary. I tried putting this logic in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear but it doesnt work. I also tried to put it inside eventstore.requestAccess but it also doesnt work. So I put it in numberOfRowsInSection which I think is wrong, but it's the only time it's populating the dictionary but doing so several times:

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        print("*****numberOfRowsInSection")
        print("numberOfRowsInSection reminders \(self.reminders.count)")

Comment: if self.reminders.count > 0 {
            for name in self.reminders {
                print("****reminder\(name.title)")
                var temp = name.title.components(separatedBy: ":")
                print("Substring result \(temp[0])")
                //var key = self.reminders[0].title // first letter of the name is the key
                var key = temp[0] // first letter of the name is the key

Comment: if var arrayForLetter = self.nameDictionary[key] { // if the key already exists
                    print("append for \(key)")
                    arrayForLetter.append(name.title) // we update the value
                    self.nameDictionary.updateValue(arrayForLetter, forKey: key)

Comment: // and we pass it to the dictionary
                } else { // if the key doesn't already exists in our dictionary
                    print("create for \(key)")
                    self.nameDictionary.updateValue([name.title], forKey: key) // we create an array with the name and add it to the dictionary
                }
                
            }
        }
        return self.reminders.count
    }

Comment: sorry, i broke the codes in 4 parts just to post it here

Comment: You need to stop posting all of this code in comments. Your original question has been asked and answered. You should close this question by accepting my answer if it solved the original issue. Then post a new question with all relevant code and details about your latest issues.